# ProBuilder objects ignores draw order overrides

Tags: unity, shaders

I have a shader which has the `ZTest` property set to always which allows me to draw an object on top of every other object. This works perfectly with all objects except ones created with ProBuilder.

Why does that happen and how do I go about fixing it?

UPDATE: i'm using a Universal render pipeline

[image: screenshot showing property]

[image: screenshot of resulting render from project]

Comment: Have you tried drawing this object in the AlphaTest, Transparent, or Overlay queues, to ensure opaque geometry doesn't draw after them (and potentially overlap)?

Comment: I'd write an answer showing how to do this, but the specific workflow depends on which renderer you're using, in which Unity version, and what type of shader graph you're working on - can you edit your question to include these details? (Ideally, debugging questions should include all the steps needed to recreate a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem, so you don't have to answer follow-up questions: readers can just reproduce the problem for themselves and test it locally)

Comment: Yes. Thank you. ProBuilder shader is actually in AlphaTest Queue, that's why it is doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depth Testing is not the same as draw order.

Changing the depth testing mode does not change when this item draws. It just says, when it *does* draw, how should it behave with respect to content that was already drawn to the depth buffer before it?

So Depth Test: Always means "always draw over everything that was drawn before me".

It says nothing about content that gets drawn *after*.

You could block any content from drawing after - by setting the Depth Write to output a depth at the camera near plane, so everything else will get depth culled, or by using a stencil value / stencil test on all your other content.

Or you could arrange things so that this item draws *last*, after anything that could potentially occlude it.

In the old built-in render pipeline, when writing shaders as text code, this was done using [the "Queue" tag in ShaderLab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html) or [material.renderQueue](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-renderQueue.html). The various implementations of graph shaders each have their own ways of controlling draw order, so we'll need a bit more detail in your question to be able to suggest the right one for the shader graph you're authoring.